# Register GET REST API route with multiple parameters

Tags: rest-api, regex

I'm trying to register a GET REST API route with multiple parameters with the following code:

```
register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/posts/?number=(?P<number>[\d]+)&amp;offset=(?P<offset>[\d]+)&amp;total=(?P<total>[\d]+)', array(
    'methods'             => 'GET',
    'callback'            => 'my_rest_function',
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    'args'                => array(
        'number' => array(
            'validate_callback' => function( $param, $request, $key ) {
                return is_numeric( $param );
            }
        ),
        'offset' => array(
            'validate_callback' => function( $param, $request, $key ) {
                return is_numeric( $param );
            }
        ),
        'total' => array(
            'validate_callback' => function( $param, $request, $key ) {
                return is_numeric( $param );
            }
        ),
    ),
) );
```

But, when I call it using for example:

https://example.com/wp-json/myplugin/v1/posts/?number=3&offset=0&total=3

I'm getting a `No route was found matching the URL and request method.` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to include query parameters in the endpoint. Just the path:

```
register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/posts', array(
    'methods'             => 'GET',
    'callback'            => 'my_rest_function',
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    'args'                => array(
        'number' => array(
            'validate_callback' => function( $param, $request, $key ) {
                return is_numeric( $param );
            }
        ),
        'offset' => array(
            'validate_callback' => function( $param, $request, $key ) {
                return is_numeric( $param );
            }
        ),
        'total' => array(
            'validate_callback' => function( $param, $request, $key ) {
                return is_numeric( $param );
            }
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Comment: Is the `args` parameter necessary, then?

Comment: If you want to require or validate certain arguments, then it can be helpful, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The request should be a regular expression, but not HTML encoded.  So, instead of `&amp;` simply use `&`.

Also, the `?` at the start of the URL query is interpreted as part of the regular expression, just meaning that the preceding `/` is optional. You have to escape it:

> \/posts\/?number=(?P[\d]+)&offset=(?P[\d]+)&total=(?P[\d]+)

To be absolutely sure you can escape the slashes, too, but AFAIK this is not necessary here.

You can test your regex [at Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: I replaced the `&amp;`s with `&` and I'm still getting the `No route was found matching the URL and request method` error. I'm calling the `register_rest_route` function in the `rest_api_init` hook.

Comment: @leemon sorry I updated my answer